# i want make multiple input in laravel livewire at same time but i got the problem

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

```html
@for ($var = 0 ; $var < $varone ; $var++)
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12" >                                            
        <div class="form-group">
            <select wire:model='product_type_one.{{ $var }}' name="product_type"class="form-control">
                <option value="">-- Select Variant {{$product_type_one}} --</option>
                <option value="color">color</option>
                <option value="size">size</option>
                <option value="other">other</option>
             </select>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <select wire:model="product_variant" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">-- Select Variant Type --</option> 
                     @foreach ($variants as $variant)
                         @if ($product_type_one==$variant->type)
                             <option value="{{$variant->variant_description}}">{{$variant->variant_description}}</option>
                         @endif
                     @endforeach
               </select>
           </div>
      </div>                     
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Inventory">
          </div>
      </div>    
@endfor
```

[image: this view]

in the back

Comment: please edit your codes

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the HTML inside a loop should only contain 1 root element inside the loop, and that element should have a `wire:key` on it.

```html
@for ($var = 0; $var < $varone; $var++) 
    <div wire:key="inputs-{{ $var }}">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select wire:model='product_type_one.{{ $var }}' name="product_type" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">-- Select Variant {{ $product_type_one }} --</option>
                    <option value="color">color</option>
                    <option value="size">size</option>
                    <option value="other">other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select wire:model="product_variant" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">-- Select Variant Type --</option>
                    @foreach ($variants as $variant)
                        @if ($product_type_one==$variant->type)
                            <option value="{{ $variant->variant_description }}">{{ $variant->variant_description }}</option>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Inventory">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endfor
```

Secondly, your `$product_variant` binding (at `<select wire:model="product_variant" class="form-control">`) also needs to be bound to an index, and it should be the same index as before, so

```html
<select wire:model="product_variant.{{ $var }}" class="form-control">
```